# How to calculate slope/tilt from IMU

Tags: electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, sensors

I have to calculate the slope/tilt from a 6 axis (3D Accelero, 3D Gyro) IMU. Are there open source libraries that help one do this or should I build it on my own? How do I get started?

Is there an open source library to calculate slope, tilt, collision, shock, turning intensity of a vehicle using an IMU? There are great FWs for flight control from which I can derive many things, but couldn't find one for automotives.